# pymongo: multiple to multiple mapping

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a database that contains the data of albums and photos, the album contains multiple photos, and photo can also be contained in multiple albums.

eg)

```
**photo collection**
photo_id    album_ids
1           [11 12 13 14]
2           [11 12 15 16]
**album collection**
album_id    photo_ids
11          [1 2]
12          [1 6]
```

Now I want to list all the photos that belongs to one user(which means multiple albums). The method that I can find out is use a nested for loop to get all the photos, put it into a list and sort it using the id number(which implies the time order).

```
for album in all the user's albums:
    get photos belonging to this album
        put it to global list
sort it
```

Is there any easier ways to do this?

Comment: Do photos not belong to a user? It would be a lot easier if you stored user IDs in the photo collection as well.

Answer (score 1):

With no access to join logic you basically have to do two queries:

1. Load the user and get his album list.
2. Query photos where album id in user's album list.

This is a common pattern in MongoDB whenever you have a many-to-many relationship. With no JOIN on the server, you basically have to write your own join on the client.

> The method that I can find out is use a nested for loop to get all the photos, put it into a list and sort it using the id number(which implies the time order)

With the structure that you have, this is basically all that you can do. Also, note that the MongoDB `ObjectId` is **not** monotonically increasing. If you are going to sort by ID it will have to be your own ID.

Also note that you can create an index on `photos` on the `album_ids` field to make the query fast. However, if you plan to use a `.sort()` and get the server to sort for you, that field needs to be part of the same index, otherwise this will throw an error.